# global variable defined in winforms not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, global-variables

I have a project in VB.Net that requires a global variable (a list of event log objects) throughout. This seemed simple enough, just define the variable and initialize in the Application's StartUp event, then access it throughout the application. Unfortunately, this only seems to work when there are no child processes (they have no access to the global variable) - so I'm way over my head as how to access the global variable from the child worker processes (if that is even possible).

The program starts several Test worker processes (that check multiple DB connections from different sources, remote web services from several sources, network checks, etc) w/ progress bars for each. If an error occurs during any of these tests, the error needs to be logged. 
The problem is that, the program cannot log events to the Windows Event system because it won't be running under an administrator account (so logging there is not possible thanks to MS's decision to prevent logging under normal user accounts w/Vista,7,8,10), the program also can't log to a text file due to it being asynchronous and the file access contention problems (immediately logging an event to a text file won't work), so I wish to log any events/errors in memory (global variable), THEN dump it to a log file AFTER all child processes complete. Make any sense?

I created a class called AppEvent

```
Public Class AppEvent

    Sub New()
        EventTime_ = Date.Now
        Level_ = EventLevel.Information
        Description_ = String.Empty
        Source_ = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private EventTime_ As Date
    Public Property EventTime() As Date
        Get
            Return EventTime_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            EventTime_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Level_ As EventLevel
    Public Property Level() As EventLevel
        Get
            Return Level_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As EventLevel)
            Level_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Description_ As String
    Public Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return Description_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Description_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Source_ As String
    Public Property Source() As String
        Get
            Return Source_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Source_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
Public Enum EventLevel
    [Information]
    [Warning]
    [Error]
    [Critical]
    [Fatal]
End Enum
```

And create a public variable just for this (and add an initial event to the AppEvents list)

```
Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        'global variable here (using this for logging asynch call errors, then dumping this into a log file when all asynch calls are complete (due to file contention of log file)
        Public AppEvents As New List(Of AppEvent)

        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            'create first event and add it to the global variable declared above
            AppEvents.Add(New AppEvent With {.EventTime = Now, .Description = "Program Started", .Level = EventLevel.Information, .Source = "QBI"})

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Next,  in my logging class, I have some methods for logging, flushing/writing the event(s)

```
Public Class AppLogging

    Public Shared Sub WriteEventToAppLog(evt As AppEvent)
        LogDataToFile(FormatLineItem(evt.EventTime, evt.Level, evt.Description, evt.Source))
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub WriteEventsToAppLog(AppEvents As List(Of AppEvent))
        Dim sbEvents As New StringBuilder
        If AppEvents.Count > 0 Then
            For Each evt In AppEvents
                sbEvents.AppendLine(FormatLineItem(evt.EventTime, evt.Level, evt.Description, evt.Source))
            Next
            LogDataToFile(sbEvents.ToString.TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function FormatLineItem(eventTime As Date, eventLevel As EventLevel, eventDescr As String, eventSource As String) As String
        Return String.Format("Logged On: {0} | Level: {1} | Details: {2} | Source: {3}", eventTime, System.Enum.GetName(GetType(EventLevel), eventLevel).Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), eventDescr, eventSource)
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub LogDataToFile(eventLogText As String, Optional ByVal LogFileName As String = "Error.log", Optional ByVal HeaderLine As String = "****** Application Log ******")
        'log file operations
        Dim LogPath As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
        If Not LogPath.EndsWith("\") Then LogPath &= "\"
        LogPath &= LogFileName

        Dim fm As FileMode
        Try
            If System.IO.File.Exists(LogPath) Then
                fm = FileMode.Append
            Else
                fm = FileMode.Create
                eventLogText = HeaderLine & Environment.NewLine & eventLogText
            End If
            Using fs As New FileStream(LogPath, fm, FileAccess.Write)
                Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
                    sw.WriteLine(eventLogText)
                End Using
            End Using
            My.Application.AppEvents.Clear() 'clears the global var
        Catch ex As Exception
            'handle this
        End Try
    End Sub


    Public Shared Sub WriteEventToMemory(eventLevel As EventLevel, eventDescription As String, Optional eventSource As String = "")
        Dim evt As New AppEvent
        evt.Description = eventDescription
        evt.Level = eventLevel
        evt.EventTime = Now
        evt.Source = eventSource
        Try
            My.Application.AppEvents.Add(evt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub FlushEventsToLogFile()
        WriteEventsToAppLog(My.Application.AppEvents)
    End Sub

End Class
```

There's a few methods in here, but the method called in every exception handler is WriteEventToMemory (it merely adds an AppEvent to the AppEvents list).

An example test routine/worker process (to the local database) looks like:

```
#Region "local db test"
    Private Sub TestLocalDBWorkerProcess_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles TestLocalDBWorkerProcess.DoWork
        Me.TestLocalDBStatusMessage = TestLocalDB()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TestLocalDBWorkerProcess_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles TestLocalDBWorkerProcess.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.prgLocalDatabase.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks
        Me.prgLocalDatabase.Value = 100

        If Me.ForcedCancelTestLocalDB Then
            Me.lbStatus.Items.Add("Local DB Test Cancelled.")
        Else
            If TestLocalDBStatusMessage.Length > 0 Then
                Me.lblLocalDatabaseStatus.Text = "Fail"
                Me.lbStatus.Items.Add(TestLocalDBStatusMessage)
                SendMessage(Me.prgLocalDatabase.Handle, 1040, 2, 0) 'changes color to red
            Else
                Me.lblLocalDatabaseStatus.Text = "OK"
                Me.lbStatus.Items.Add("Connection to local database is good.")
                Me.prgLocalDatabase.ForeColor = Color.Green
            End If
        End If
        Me.ForcedCancelTestLocalDB = False
        Me.TestLocalDBProcessing = False
        ProcessesFinished()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartTestLocalDB()
        Me.prgLocalDatabase.Value = 0
        Me.prgLocalDatabase.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight)
        Me.prgLocalDatabase.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
        Me.TestLocalDBProcessing = True
        Me.TestLocalDBStatusMessage = String.Empty
        Me.lblLocalDatabaseStatus.Text = String.Empty
        TestLocalDBWorkerProcess = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        With TestLocalDBWorkerProcess
            .WorkerReportsProgress = True
            .WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
            .RunWorkerAsync()
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Function TestLocalDB() As String
        Dim Statusmessage As String = String.Empty
        Try
            If Me.TestLocalDBWorkerProcess.CancellationPending Then
                Exit Try
            End If
            If Not QBData.DB.TestConnection(My.Settings.DBConnStr3) Then
                Throw New Exception("Unable to connect to local database!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Statusmessage = ex.Message
            AppLogging.WriteEventToMemory(EventLevel.Fatal, ex.Message, "TestLocalDB")
        End Try
        Return Statusmessage
    End Function
#End Region
```

The try-catch block simply catches the exception and writes it to memory (I just wrapped it in the WriteEventToMemory method, but it's just adding it to the AppEvents list:  My.Application.AppEvents.Add(evt)

Everything appeared to be working peachy, until I noticed that the count for AppEvents was (1) after the Startup event, then it's count was (0) from any of the child processes, finally, the count was (1) when the list was dumped to the error log file (only the first event added was there). It is clearly acting like there are multiple versions of the AppEvents variable.

```
****** Application Log ******
Logged On: 10/7/2016 6:01:45 PM | Level: Information | Details: Program Started | Source: QBI
```

Only the first event shows up, the other events not (they are added, there's no null ref exceptions or any exceptions - like phantoms). Any event added to the global variable on the MAIN thread stays (and gets logged, ultimately). So this is clearly a multithreaded issue (never tried this before in a Windows app).
Any ideas on how to remedy?

Comment: Thats a lot of code.  Other than `MyApplication_Startup` I cant see where you are adding anything to the list.  see [MCVE]

Comment: WriteEventToMemory method is the only place that adds an AppEvent to AppEvents list.
I can't really make a mutlthreaded example any smaller than what is there (unless I just remove that)

Comment: I just ran into the solution - global variables are not thread-safe for one even if it did work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563825/global-variable-in-asp-net#7564075

Comment: There are specialty collections for that - not really to do with scope

Comment: I'm aware of this, however, the EventLog methods ONLY works when the app is running as an Administrator account - making it worthless as I mentioned before. The second roadblock is trying to get multiple threads to access and write to a simple text file, but the file could be held open (and often is) by other processes.

Comment: I got it figured out and will post the answer. In brief, I had to pass the AppEvent through the method itself (for all the different methods/subs), then, in the RunWorkerCompleted method, log the event as the global variable was only valid in the main process. It works like a charm - no contentions, no errors.  I'll post the answer below here soon.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, I had to pass the events back to the calling workerprocess, so, in the main form I put in:

```
   Private AppEvent_TestLocalDB As New AppEvent
```

In the DoWork (for each process), I changed it to:

```
Private Sub TestLocalDBWorkerProcess_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles TestLocalDBWorkerProcess.DoWork
    Me.TestLocalDBStatusMessage = TestLocalDB(AppEvent_TestLocalDB)
End Sub
```

The TestLocalDB sub now looks like:

```
Private Function TestLocalDB(ByRef aEvent As AppEvent) As String
    Dim Statusmessage As String = String.Empty
    Try
        If Me.TestLocalDBWorkerProcess.CancellationPending Then
            Exit Try
        End If
        If Not QBData.DB.TestConnection(My.Settings.DBConnStr3) Then
            Throw New Exception("Unable to connect to local database!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Statusmessage = ex.Message
        With aEvent
            .Description = ex.Message
            .Level = EventLevel.Fatal
            .Source = "TestLocalDB"
        End With
    End Try
    Return Statusmessage
End Function
```

Note there is no error logging, just the event variable (ByRef to pass it back, the equivalent to C# out).
When the worker process completes, I add the following:

```
    With AppEvent_TestLocalDB
        AppLogging.WriteEventToMemory(.Level, .Description, .Source)
    End With
```

(the other worker processes work the same way)
When ALL the processes are complete, then I flush it to the log file.

```
   AppLogging.FlushEventsToLogFile()
```

Now the custom event/error log entries look like so (with a freshly made file):

```
****** Application Log ******
Logged On: 10/7/2016 10:14:36 PM | Level: Information | Details: Program Started | Source: QBI
Logged On: 10/7/2016 10:14:53 PM | Level: Fatal | Details: Unable to connect to local database! | Source: TestLocalDB
```

That was it - just pass the variable back to the caller